# Java Canvas only increasing in size

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I have a JPanel which layout is BorderLayout and i have a Canvas added to that , so basically the canvas should fill out the JPanel and in fact that is what happening .

now the problem is resizing , when i resize the frame on which the JPanel is , the canvas is only increasing in size . What i mean is if i increase the size of the JFrame (by draging the mouse after running ), the JPanel increases in size and also the Canvas . But if i decrease only the Canvas stays in the size it took before .

I am sure of that because i added a listenner to the panel so it would print the size of the Canvas in System.out ...

I need this to work for a media player ... it is working perfectly till i decide to make it smaller .Here's the code:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent media;
MediaPlayerFactory fact;
EmbeddedMediaPlayer player;
MediaListPlayer listPlayer;
MediaList list;
CanvasVideoSurface surface;
private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent media1;

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss.SSS");
Canvas cnv;
boolean done=false;
  public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
            RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC"
    );
    pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

    media = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

    this.setLocation(100, 100);
    this.setSize(200, 200);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);

    cnv = new Canvas();
    cnv.setVisible(true);
    pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pnl.add(cnv);
    fact = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    player = media.getMediaPlayer();

    surface = fact.newVideoSurface(cnv);
    player.setVideoSurface(surface);
    media.getMediaPlayer().setVideoSurface(surface);

    listPlayer = fact.newMediaListPlayer();
    listPlayer.setMediaPlayer(player);
    list = fact.newMediaList();
    listPlayer.setMediaList(list);
    listPlayer.setMode(MediaListPlayerMode.LOOP);

    done=true;
    }
    private void pnlAncestorResized(java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
 if(done){

     System.out.println("x " + cnv.getWidth() + " y " + cnv.getHeight());
 }
}
```

PS : im not sure if BorderLayout is needed , i think by default a component takes up all of its container space when added ... so if i may also get an answer to that

**UPDATE**: i tried the solution [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1289337?start=0&tstart=0) and it worked , no idea why setting min size makes it work .

Thank you

Comment: 1) You will want to create and post a very small and in fact [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one we can run, test, and hopefully improve. 2) Out of curiosity, w
hy are you using a Canvas, an AWT component, with a Swing GUI?

Comment: 2) cause the media player only draws on canvas , and i tried doin it with a AWT panel but same result

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels 1)done